# @WebServlet annotation doesn't work

Tags: java, tomcat, annotations, servlet-3.0

I checked the following possible answers but not found fix for my problem
 1. [@WebServlet annotation with Tomcat 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6535676/webservlet-annotation-with-tomcat-7)
 2. [@WebServlet annotation not recognized; init doesn't run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7024047/webservlet-annotation-not-recognized-init-doesnt-run)
 3. [@WebServlet annotation doesn't work with Tomcat 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26089902/webservlet-annotation-doesnt-work-with-tomcat-8)

Here is my servlet-api.jar info:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.4
Created-By: 1.6.0_37-b06 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
X-Compile-Source-JDK: 1.6
X-Compile-Target-JDK: 1.6

Name: javax/servlet/
Specification-Title: Java API for Servlets
Specification-Version: 3.0
Specification-Vendor: Sun Microsystems, Inc.
Implementation-Title: javax.servlet
Implementation-Version: 3.0.FR
Implementation-Vendor: Apache Software Foundation
```

My example class code:

```
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;                                                           
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/ProcessPayment")
public class ProcessPayment extends javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet{


public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)throws IOException, ServletException{

        res.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
        StringWriter sWriter = new StringWriter();  
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(sWriter);         
try{
    SiteTemplate st     = new SiteTemplate();   
    PaymentDecorator pd = new PaymentDecorator();
    out.print(
        st.header(req)+st.headerButtons(req)+
            "<tr><td>"+
                pd.ccform(300,"6",1)+
            "</td></tr>"+
        st.footer());   

}catch(Exception ee){
        ErrorCheck ec = new ErrorCheck();
        ec.errorMsg("ERROR: GSW.ProcessPayment.java", ee);
}
res.getWriter().print(sWriter.toString());
}
}
```

My web.xml:

```
<web-app 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
```

When I access it like: `http://127.0.0.1:7070/ProcessPayment` then following message appears:

> HTTP Status 404 - /ProcessPayment
>
> type Status report
>
> message /ProcessPayment
>
> description The requested resource (/ProcessPayment) is not available.
>
> Apache Tomcat/6.0.18

I updated servlet-api but my Tomcat version in Release Note file is:

> Apache Tomcat Version 6.0.18

Please advise as to why @WebServlet annotation is not working?`

Comment: What do you mean by not working? You entered the URL and nothing show up? or error msgs are shown? I guess we need more details

Comment: I have updated my question by adding error message at the end

Comment: Simply guessing,your URL is localhost:XXXX/Yourprojectname/ProcessPayment? You may try localhost:XXXX/Yourprojectname/servlet/ProcessPayment

Comment: my class is in ROOT folder

Comment: in your access url where is your project name ? It should be like http://127.0.0.1:7070/YourProjectName/ProcessPayment

Comment: My file is in root not in project folder

Comment: I even renamed ROOT to MyFolder and accessed `http://127.0.0.1:7070/MyFolder/ProcessPayment` that displays error 404

Comment: Have you solved it or you still need help?

Comment: not yet fixed. plz help me

Comment: When I add this servlet entries in web.xml then working fine but why its not working as @WebServlet?

Comment: I update my question and added tomcat 64 bit version i.e. `Apache Tomcat Version 6.0.18`

Comment: @PatrickSo I can give teamviewer access to my labtop to fix this problem

Comment: indeed if you have already fixed it by putting entries in web.xml why bother using @WebServlet, anyway ,here is the solution: @WebServlet(name="Controller", urlPatterns={"/index.html","/login", "/show_dbs"}), just change it yourself

Comment: @PSo I already tried this fix. Can you please check it via teamviewer?

Comment: show your complete xml file